# How to get mesh triangles

Tags: qt, qt3d

I'm creating meshes with `Qt3D`. I check if the mesh is actually built with triangles:

```
qDebug() << "mesh primitive type: " << mesh->primitiveType();
```

which returns:

```
Qt3DRender::QGeometryRenderer::PrimitiveType(Triangles)
```

Therefore, my mesh primitive type is definitely `triangle`.

---

Now I'm trying to access to triangles of the mesh, but I don't know how. There is the following API to get the `data` and its `type` which can be either `VertexBuffer` or `IndexBuffer`:

```
mesh->geometry()->attributes().at(i)->buffer()->data();
mesh->geometry()->attributes().at(i)->buffer()->type();
```

But I don't know how to **extract triangles** one-by-one using the above APIs. Can anybody help me.

---

Eventually, I'm going to export the triangles as STL file with [such a format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STL_(file_format)#Binary_STL).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I used `index` buffer and `vertex` buffer to access mesh triangles and export them in STL file format. The method is described here:

[Understanding the mesh created by Qt3D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52039817/understanding-the-mesh-created-by-qt3d)